# Is it possible to usort a multidimensional array in PHP to be ordered by alternative values, i.e 1/0/1/0/1/0

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

If you have this PHP array:

```
$args = array(
    'a' => array(
        'order' => 1,
    ),
    'b' => array(
        'order' => 0,
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'order' => 0,
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'order' => 0,
    ),
    'e' => array(
        'order' => 1,
    ),
);
```

Is there a way to use usort (or other) method that can order it by multidimensional key's value, but instead of being "incremental" (0,0,0,1,1), they would alternate (0,1,0,1,0).

So using the array above as an example, the desired order output is for the keys to be ordered by alternate "order" key value:

```
$args = array(
    'b' => array(
        'order' => 0,
    ),
    'a' => array(
        'order' => 1,
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'order' => 0,
    ),
    'e' => array(
        'order' => 1,
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'order' => 0,
    ),

);
```

In short; The keys are now ordered by the value of the key called "order" 
 and alternate in value, so they are: 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.

I simply can't figure this one out!

Comment: You would probably need to use a custom callback to do that. [See uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Comment: what do you mean by alternative values? and how is that sorted?

Comment: Look at the desired output, you'll notice the keys are ordered by the "order" key's value, but instead of being: 0,0,0,1,1 - the desired order is 0,1,0,1,0.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution anyway (without sorting)? What should happen if there are 2+ more `1`s than there are `0`s, or the other way around? Should the remaining items be appended to the end anyway?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for any solution, the order of duplicate values doesn't matter, as long as the final array has keys with alternating "order" value (which can only be 1 or 0).

Comment: @Sometip The question was not about duplicate keys, but duplicate order values: what if the input is `0,0,0,0,1`, or `0,1,1,1,1` - there is no way for those to alternate, so what should happen? Discard the values which can't be placed? Stack them all at the end? Detect the condition and raise an error?

Comment: Oh I see, in that case just append the extras at the end, indeed! As this question was very specific "Is it possible to use usort"... I've accepted the correct answer and created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862704/how-to-order-zebra-array-so-each-key-has-an-alternate-value-either-1-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Ordering means that you can compare two elements and determine which order they should have. Your query fails at that when you have two `1` elements.

However, that doesn't mean that it can't be done algorithmically, only that sorting or ordering is *not* the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks! This is the correct answer to my question. I've made a more specific one for algorithmic solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862704/how-to-order-zebra-array-so-each-key-has-an-alternate-value-either-1-0