# Order rows by their column value to create repeating sequences of ascending values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, alternating

I want to order my associative rows by their column value as sequences of ascending values.

Sample array1:

```
$args = [
    'a' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'b' => ['zebra' => 0],
    'c' => ['zebra' => 0],
    'd' => ['zebra' => 0],
    'e' => ['zebra' => 1],
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    'b' => ['zebra' => 0],
    'a' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'c' => ['zebra' => 0],
    'e' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'd' => ['zebra' => 0],
]
```

Notice that duplicate values are not consecutive while sorting ascending.  Instead, all unique, first-encountered values come first, then second encountered values, etc.

Sample array2:

```
$args = [
    'a' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'b' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'c' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'd' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'e' => ['zebra' => 0],
    'f' => ['zebra' => 0],
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    'e' => ['zebra' => 0],
    'a' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'f' => ['zebra' => 0],
    'b' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'c' => ['zebra' => 1],
    'd' => ['zebra' => 1],
]
```

Edit: I tried to do this with usort, via [this similar, but different, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861053/is-it-possible-to-usort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php-to-be-ordered-by-alterna/59862459#59862459), and the answer was no, so I am looking for a programatic solution (without usort).

Comment: There is not always a solution, what should be done if there is only `0` or `1` ?

Comment: That's not *exactly* the same question

Comment: No, the other question was about Usort, which someone said was not possible, and that was the correct answer. This one is looking for an algorithmic solution now.

Comment: @Sometip before having any hope to see this question being re-opened, you should edit your question and add your attempts to solve your problem (and then, I will nominate this question for re-opening)

Comment: Thanks Cid, I've edited it now referring to the previous usort question :)

Comment: @Sometip that's not an attempt to solve it. I see no code in your question.

Comment: @Ôrel then it should just output 0,1 :)

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement. Why are you trying to do this? There may be a better solution you aren't even considering

Comment: @Sometip my question is what to do if there is only 1 (or only 0, or not the correct number to be able to do a valid solution)

Comment: Here is how to implement [my advice on the dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807468/2943403) with this question's sample data: https://3v4l.org/uDZ4k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same idea to split the input into the 1's and 0's, then output a 0 and a 1 as long as there is something left to output.  As each time you output a value, the array is reduced, this just continues till both lists are empty so should cope with unbalanced lists...

```
$temp = [ 0 => [], 1 => []];

foreach($args as $key=>$value){
    $temp[$value['zebra']][] = $key;
}

$output = [];
while ( !empty($temp[0]) || !empty($temp[1]) )   {
    if ( !empty($temp[0]) )   {
        $next = array_shift($temp[0]);
        $output [$next] = $args[$next];
    }
    if ( !empty($temp[1]) )   {
        $next = array_shift($temp[1]);
        $output [$next] = $args[$next];
    }
}
```

Comment: [One bug](https://3v4l.org/HT9kA) here could be in case when `1`'s less than `0`'s. And [vice versa](https://3v4l.org/fqNtj)... hm

Comment: @AksenP, should have tested that, just changed it to `!empty($temp[0]) || !empty($temp[1])` so it carries on if either list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use deconstruction with count of comparison.

At first step you can collect all indexes with `zebra = 1` and with `zebra = 0`:

```
$zeros = [];
$ones = [];

foreach($args as $let=>$arg){
    if ($arg['zebra'] === 1) {
        $ones[] = $let;
    } else if ($arg['zebra'] === 0) {
        $zeros[] = $let;
    }
}
```

And now you can construct resultant array like:

```
if(abs(count($zeros) - count($ones)) === 1) {    // if their difference equal to 1
    if (count($ones) > count($zeros)){           // if $ones is bigger
        foreach($zeros as $ind=>$let){ 
            $res[$ones[$ind]] = ['zebra' => 1];
            $res[$let]        = ['zebra' => 0];  
            $tmp = $ind;
        } 
        $res[$ones[$tmp+1]] = ['zebra' => 1];
    } else if (count($ones) < count($zeros)){      // if $zeros is bigger
        foreach($ones as $ind=>$let){ 
            $res[$zeros[$ind]] = ['zebra' => 0];
            $res[$let]        = ['zebra' => 1];  
            $tmp = $ind;
        } 
        $res[$zeros[$tmp+1]] = ['zebra' => 0];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [b] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 0
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 1
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 0
        )

    [e] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 1
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 0
        )

)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/D3FO1)**

If you need result in case of (1,0,1,0,0) use next constructor:

```
    if (count($ones) > count($zeros)){
        foreach($ones as $ind=>$let){ 
            if (isset($zeros[$ind])) $res[$zeros[$ind]] = ['zebra' => 0]; 
            $res[$let]        = ['zebra' => 1];  
        }  
    } else if (count($zeros) > count($ones)){
        foreach($zeros as $ind=>$let){ 
            $res[$let]        = ['zebra' => 0];  
            if (isset($ones[$ind])) $res[$ones[$ind]] = ['zebra' => 1]; 
        }  
    }
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [b] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 0
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 1
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 0
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 1
        )

    [e] => Array
        (
            [zebra] => 0
        )

)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6juoe)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `array_map` after grabbing 1s and 0s in separate arrays:

```
$args0 = array_filter($args, function ($arg) {
  return $arg['zebra'] === 0;
});
$args1 = array_filter($args, function ($arg) {
  return $arg['zebra'] === 1;
});

$result = array_merge(...array_map(static function ($arg0Key, $arg1Key) use ($args0, $args1) {
  if ($arg0Key !== null) {
    $result[$arg0Key] = $args0[$arg0Key];
  }
  if ($arg1Key !== null) {
    $result[$arg1Key] = $args1[$arg1Key];
  }
  return $result;
}, array_keys($args0), array_keys($args1)));

print_r($result);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/sfqeq**

Note: using two `array_filter` to separate values looks nice but loops over `$args` twice; prefer a simple loop if the initial array can be somewhat big. This is not the relevant part of the answer, though.